# Can a value of a var in @IBDesignable depend on external values, such as a frame of a view?

Tags: ios, cashapelayer, layoutsubviews, ibdesignable

I want to draw a shape hole in an @IBDesignable view. For this I need the **size of a view**, which is **above in the view hierarchy**. This view changes it's size by constraints.

> How to retrieve the frame? May this is not possible at all, because the view we are depending on is drawn later? But it's frame size may be retrievable early?

```
<MainView>
   |  <View>
   |  |  <ViewWithShape>
   |  <ViewWeDependOn>
```

The shape is drawn in layoutSubviews:

```
   override func layoutSubviews() {
      super.layoutSubviews()
      if !(holeLayer != nil) {

         holeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
         layer.mask = holeLayer

         let rect = bounds // I need the frame HERE
         let path = UIBezierPath(quadrantHoleInsideRect: rect)

         holeLayer.path = path.CGPath
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I put this question, because my first obvious **solution** would have been a **outlet to the depending view from within the @IBDesignable view**.

> This gave me a crash at first, but it is now working as expected.

Comment: But the ability of **life rendering is gone**: _error: IB Designables: Failed to render instance of xyView: The agent crashed_